# Как обеспечить перенос строк по Enter?

Tags: jquery, html

Делаю онлайн редактор html. Весь код/текст пишется в div'e, при нажатии enter'a происходит перенос строки. Но, когда использую `$('div').html()`, к примеру, переносы строк исчезают.
Собственно вопрос. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии enter'a добавлялся тег "br"? Или как еще можно решить проблему?

Comment: если для себя или админа - ContentEditable

Comment: Что вы хотели этим сказать?

Comment: ContentEditable это новый атрибут тэгов html, поэтому работать будет не везде. [вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/7Ch2p/)

Comment: [тут пишут что IE>=7, ](http://marakana.com/s/post/1096/using_the_html5_attribute_contenteditable_to_create_a_wysiwyg) весь урок не вычитывал, и за качество не поручусь, но на поверхностный взгляд вроде-бы грамотно написано.

Comment: А как это связано с вопросом?

Comment: > Или как еще можно решить проблему?

использовать ContentEditable